# Android EditText does not return the correct UTF-8 text

Tags: android, encoding, utf-8, android-edittext

I have an Edittext to fill in the search string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

  <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/search_input_edittext"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

  <Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/add_to_cart_btn"
    android:text="@string/search"
    android:id="@+id/search_search_btn"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

But the Vietnamese word that I type in is not properly `getText().getString()`. It is supposed to be (I typed this one manually)

> củ

but what I got from the code:

```
EditText search_edittext = (EditText) v_iew.findViewById(R.id.search_input_edittext); //v_iew is from inflating for `AlertDialog`
search_edittext.getText().toString();
```

is like the image below:

[image]

I think they are differently encoded. The hook must be above the "u". But if I copy the whole word and paste to any editor, it shows exactly the same. This is what it looks like when I paste it here:

> củ

and this is what happen if I copy the hook only

> ̉

They look the same but what from the `EditText` cannot be used for further works.

If I copy the word from the internet and paste into the search field, it works! So it's my input method that caused the problem. Tried to search for converting them to unicode (the one with \xxxx) but no luck.

Anyone has any idea on how to convert the input to "normal format"? Thank you for your time!

Comment: To get it in the format that you are asking you need to use Normalisation form C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're having trouble with sending the right formatted text through API, just set UTF(Assuming, its an UTF font you're using) support in HttpClient. Don't worry about what shows in Log. Custom fonts are prone to render incorrectly at Log.

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(payload, "UTF-8");

post.setEntity(stringEntity);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Update: If only part of URL needs to be encoded then use it like following,

```
String url = URLEncoder.encode(params[0], "utf-8");
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
//Rest of the code
```

Comment: This is my code for my GET method. Where should I place the UTF-8 as you suggested? `HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                        response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
                jsonResult = jsonResult.substring(6);`

Comment: I modified the code a little. The way you currently executing a POST request doesn't seem to have any payloads. The StringEntity takes your POST payload/params(NameValuePair or JSON object) and encodes it for UTF.

Comment: oh sorry, forgot to mention. The params[0] is the whole link with the GET params.

Comment: Thank you! You're life saver!

Comment: Glad it works! Another thing, try to use HttpGet & HttpPost according to your API type(for instance, you could've used HttpGet for this API since the API itself is a plain GET API). Otherwise, often you might get into trouble figuring out the reason behind API invoking errors.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:
String sNFC = Normalizer.normalize(search_edittext.getText().toString(), Normalizer.Form.NFC);

Answer (score 0):

this is the only solution I found after hours of search.

```
String urlParameters = "";//sn=C02G8416DRJM&cn=&locale=&caller=&num=12345
    if(parameters != null) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {

            String val;
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(entry.getValue()))
                val = URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue());
            else
                val = "";

            urlParameters += entry.getKey() + "=" + val + "&";
        }
    }
```